# saxon:send-mail function return java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: xslt, saxon

I'm using oXygen editor XML Editor 19.0 with Saxon-EE 9.7.0.15.

I wrote the simple stylesheet below in order to test the saxon:send-mail function but, every time I try to run it, Saxon return a java.lang.NullPointerException error. Extended functions (-ext) are activated. I also get the same error with Saxon-PE.

Does anybody have an idea where the error may come from?

Here is the stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0">

    <xsl:variable name="mailSetup" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)">
        <xsl:map>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'to'" select="'me@gmail.com'"/>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'from'" select="'me@gmail.com'"/>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'smtp-server'" select="'smtp.gmail.com'"/>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'username'" select="'me@gmail.com'"/>
            <xsl:map-entry key="'password'" select="'mepassword'"/>
        </xsl:map>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="html" as="xs:string">
      <![CDATA[ <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Test saxon:send-mail</h1>
                <p>Test Ok</p>
            </body>
        </html>]]> 
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template name="main">
        <xsl:value-of select="saxon:send-mail($mailSetup, 'Test', $html, ())"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It appears that Saxon uses the javax.mail API which is not part of the Java SE so you might need to install it from https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release and put it on the class path. I have not checked whether that fixes the issue.

Comment: It seems putting that jar on the class path and running Saxon from the command line does not fix the issue, with 9.7 I get the NullPointerException you say you get inside oXygen, with 9.8 I get a RuntimeException caused by a NullPointerException.

Comment: And oXygen seems to come with a `mailapi.jar` already.

Comment: With a NullPointerException, it always helps to give a stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logged here as a Saxon bug:

https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3400

The NPE occurs if any of the mail options is missing from the map. In your case the missing option is realname.

The options are documented here:

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/send-mail

except that the "cc" option seems to be missing from the documentation.

Comment: The html option is also needed.

Comment: Is there a way to ask that the connection be SSL?

Comment: You may be able to configure it by setting Java system properties, see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail145sslnotes-1562622.html